# my simple calculator in python doesnt work with negative numbers

Tags: python, calculator

I'm trying to code a very simple calculator in python. The problem is it works perfectly when I give positive numbers but I don't get any answer when I enter negative numbers... I can't figure out why.
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me :).
Here's my code:

```
print("Hi :) This is your simple calculator")

a = float(input("please enter the first number: "))

b = float(input("please enter the second number: "))

print(f"{a}+{b} is {round((a)+(b), 3)}, {a}-{b} is {round(a-(b), 3)}, {b}-{a} is {round(b-(a), 3)}, {a}*{b} is {round(a*(b), 3)}, {a}/{b} is {round(a/(b), 3 )}, {b}/{a} is {round(b/(a), 3)}, {a} to the power of {b} is {round((a)**(b), 3)}, {b}to the power of{a} is {round((b)**(a), 3)}, {b} root of {a} is {round((a)**(1/b), 3)}, {a} root of {b} is {round((b)**(1/a), 3)} ")
```

Comment: What _do_ you get when you enter negative numbers? That's important to mention when you're asking for help. Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the print statement revised (without the roots). This part seems to work.

```
print(f"{a}+{b} is {round((a)+(b), 3)}, {a}-{b} is {round(a-(b), 3)}, {b}-{a} is {round(b-(a), 3)}, {a}{b} is {round(a * b, 3)}, {a} to the power of {b} is {round(a ** b, 3)}, {b}to the power of{a} is {round(b ** a, 3)}")
```

I took off the roots because you would run into problems with roots of negative numbers. For complex numbers look up the [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it. The problem is that you cannot take the nth root of negative numbers. This will lead to imaginary numbers that you will need to use [c.math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html) for. Also, you need to be careful with division of 0's. I have made some if-else conditions if a user has `a` to be a negative number or `b` to be a negative number.

```
import math
print("Hi :) This is your simple calculator")

a = float(input("please enter the first number: "))
b = float(input("please enter the second number: "))

print(str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + ' is ' + str(round(a + b, 3)))
print(str(a) + ' - ' + str(b) + ' is ' + str(round(a - b, 3)))
print(str(b) + ' - ' + str(a) + ' is ' + str(round(b - a, 3)))
print(str(a) + ' * ' + str(b) + ' is ' + str(round(a * b, 3)))

if b == 0:
    print('Error! Cannot divide a by 0!')
else:
    print(str(a) + ' / ' + str(b) + ' is ' + str(round(a / b, 3)))
    
if a == 0:
    print('Error! Cannot divide b by 0!')
else:
    print(str(b) + ' / ' + str(a) + ' is ' + str(round(b / a, 3)))

if (a < 0 or b == 0):
    print('Please enter a positive number for a.')
else:
    print(str(a) + ' ** ' + str(b) + ' is ' + str(round(pow(a, b), 3)))
    print(str(a) + ' root ' + str(b) + ' is ' + str(round(pow(a, (1/float(b))), 3)))

if (b < 0 or a == 0):
    print('Please enter a positive number for b.')
else:
    print(str(b) + ' ** ' + str(a) + ' is ' + str(round(pow(b, a), 3)))
    print(str(b) + ' root ' + str(a) + ' is ' + str(round(pow(b, (1/float(a))), 3)))
```